# In this c# file, did I just declare an instance within its own class?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# syntax and I just created a new file using Visual Studio.  I added the static Main method however the syntax above it was already in the file when it was created.  I'm coming from a Swift background so I'd like to know if this file created an instance of itself within its own class?

Here is the code:

```
using System;

public class Blueberry
{
    public Blueberry()
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {

    }

}
```

The part in question which doesn't make sense is the following:

```
public Blueberry()
    {
    }
```

What is this code implying?

Comment: It is a constructor, it is called when an instance is created, it doesn't (really) create an instance of the class. [Constructors on Docs.Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors). If you aren't putting any code in there, and you don't have any other constructors, it can be omitted entirely.

Comment: @CosmicArrows AS Ron said, that is called a constructor, a class can have many or none, if none is defined, the compiler will create a default parameterless constructor like in your example. You can use a constructor to initialize properties of your class on instantiation, so if class BlueBerry had a property named IsJuicy of type boolean, you could have a constructor that accepts a boolean and sets the propert IsJuicy to the value passed to the constructor like so `Blueberry myBerry = new Blueberry(true);`

Comment: You might consider taking a basic tutorial in C# or reading the first couple chapters of an introductory text. If your plan is to ask a SO question every time you're confused by some inobvious piece of syntax, that's a very inefficient way to learn.

Comment: It's a constructor. That's all you need to know to find several hundred examples and explanations out there on the web.

Answer (score 5):

It's a constructor. In Swift, that method would be called `init`. In C#, the constructor has the same name as the class.  As is also the case in Java and C++.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access object methods, attributes, properties etc., without instance of the class. So, in Main function (which is static) you cannot access stuff from Blueberry, unless you create instance

```
using System;

public class Blueberry
{
    public Blueberry()
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
         Blueberry b = new Bluberry();
    }
}
```

Now you have created instance of Blueberry class, and you should call Blueberry methods etc., via b variable.

```
public Blueberry()
{
}
```

This is constructor. It is called when you create new instance of an object. New instance is called with keyword new. So whenever you say new then the constructor will be called.